# Angular2 PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES in rc.5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just migrated from rc.4 to rc.5. However, my custom directives that I did define for the whole app aren't recognized anymore.

I used to have in my app.component :

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
 provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [CustomDirective1, CustomDirective2], multi: true})
])
```

Now with the NgModule I do have :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [
      provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [CustomDirective1, CustomDirective2], multi: true})
    ],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
})
```

CustomDirective1 and CustomDirective2 are not recognized anymore though in my app. Is there anything else I should be doing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Directives should go in a module's declarations](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#declarations):

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CustomDirective1,
        CustomDirective2
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

Comment: PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES doesn't make any sense anymore then ?

Comment: Looks like it's not even in the API documentation anymore https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/#!?apiFilter=_directives